# How to make a fork bomb with fishshell?

Tags: fish

I want to make a fork bomb with [fishshell](https://fishshell.com/), but `:(){ :|: & };:` doesn't work and gives the error

> fish: Command substitutions not allowed
> :(){ :|: & };

How can I make a fork bomb with fishshell?

Comment: Do you know how to define a function in fish? Do you know how to put something in the background? Did you try piping one copy of that function to another copy of that function, and putting that in the background? The classic POSIX fork bomb is only particularly notable because it goes out of its way to look obscure; you don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: That is to say, if you rewrite the original to `forkbomb() { forkbomb | forkbomb & }; forkbomb`, it's arguably a lot more obvious what it's doing, and thus more obvious how to translate it. If there's a specific place you get stuck, _show your work_; we generally refuse "please rewrite this code from language-X to language-Y for me" requests when they don't show effort, and I don't see a reason to treat this one differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax would have to be

```
function forkbomb
    forkbomb | forkbomb &
end
forkbomb
```

but:

1. fish currently cannot background functions - it has no notion of forking off subshells, so there's no "fork" in your bomb
2. fish recognizes that the function calls itself immediately and refuses because that's infinite recursion.

What you *can* do is call fish manually, and define the function inside it:

```
function forkbomb
    fish -C "$(functions forkbomb)" -c forkbomb | fish -C "$(functions forkbomb)" -c forkbomb &
end
```

Trigger it by running `forkbomb`. For obvious reasons this can bring your system to a halt.